# SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop

Tags: python, python-2.x

Вот мой код:

```
import ssl
import urllib
from termcolor import colored
good = colored('Good', 'green')
bad = colored('Bad', 'red')
handle = open('goodip.txt')
buf = []
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
for ip in handle:
    buf.append(ip)
try:
    for x in buf:
        urllib.urlopen('http://' + x, context=context)
        print x, good
except: 
    print x, bad
    continue
```

Выдает такую ошибку:SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop
Пытался закинуть это в бесконечный цикл, но когда он возвращался к началу, все начиналось заново, как можно перестроить мой код?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[continue](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue) вне цикла смысла не имеет, о чём в ошибке и написано.

```
for x in buf:
    try:
        urllib.urlopen('http://' + x, context=context)
    except:
        print x, bad
        continue
    print x, good
```